# WCF Service to read, write, edit, delete data from SQL database And Be Consumed by MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build a web service in .NET, which will interact with an SQL database. This web service will later on be consumed by an MVC where this data will be displayed and interacted with.

I have the database ready, the connection between the database and the web service has been made. I am yet to add my MVC item into my solution.

I am quite new using ASP .NET, please, I could use some help in accessing my Web Service from the MVC application and being able to edit, add, delete records because I am not sure of my next direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right click on the project and select "Add">"Service Reference" then give it the end point address. Then just get the Client to make the calls.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out some of this tutorial will teach you exactly how to deal with it

Actually, it's helped me a lot when I started

http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm

Then Have a look on this:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d13d20/creating-aspnet-mvc-app-with-wcf-service-docx/

But generally speaking, you can add a web service reference and endpoint info in the main Web.Config file but I suspect you are having trouble with calling the WCF service URL, if so I posted an example of a generic class/wrapper for calling WCF web services in an MVC application.

#### Add the Web Reference to Visual Studio :

1. Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Choose Add–> Service Reference –> Then click the Advanced Button... –>
3. Then click the "Add Web Reference…" button –> then type the address of your Web Service into the URL box. Then click the green arrow and Visual Studio will discover your Web Services and display them.

Wish you the best :)

Comment: I tried that, thank you. However, this does not display my records from the database as intended. It just displays an empty list on the webpage, with "Create", "Edit", "Details" and "Delete". I can't access them.

Comment: Hi, so I have my View working. I am trying to have CRUD operations in my application for the student records. Can you help me with the codes for this

Comment: Ya sure posts it on